# derivation for expected value for variance

Tags: probability, distribution, variance

[image: derivation of the expected value for the variance]

Hi Im taking a course about probability distribution in datascience and below  is  derivation of the expected value for the variance

1. Variance = expected value of the squared difference from mean for any value. But generally, variance is just the difference between the value and its mean.

Why are we squaring and adding the expected value symbol?

$$\sigma^2 = E((Y - \mu)^2) = E(Y^2) - \mu^2$$

2. For the first step in derivation, why do we multiply the summation of $p(x)$  with  $(x - \mu)^2$?
   [image]
3. How is this substitution valid? I cannot understand it. I know that  $E(X)=p(X).X$

$E(X^2) = \sum P(X)*X^2$

Answer (score 0):

The expected value of a random variable is defined as (without entering into probability/measure theory):

- For discrete distribution $F$, we have $E(X)=\sum_x P_F(X=x) x$
- For (absolutely) continuous distribution $F=\int f(x) dx$, we have $E(X) = \int f(x) dx$

Therefore, the first equality is just the definition of expected value for the discrete case.

And finally, the [law of the unconscious statistician (LOTUS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) states that
$$E(g(X)) = \int g(x) f(x) dx$$ (for continuous F), or
$$E(g(X)) = \sum g(x) P(X=x)$$ (for discrete F).

Comment: Thanks but this dose not answer my question i already mention in point 3. that i know E(X)=p(X).X   ,my question is on how LHS=RHS equations in above point 2,3 ?

Comment: @Aj_MLstater What about now?

Comment: Im totaly confused , can you please explain these part alone    2.  E(X-mu) ^2 = summation p(X) *(X-mu)^2         3. E(X^2)=p(X).X^2

Comment: @Aj_MLstater Take $g(X)=(X-E(X))^2$ in the LOTUS equation, and the rest follows. I've edited my question to reflect the LOTUS for the discrete case.

Comment: @Aj_MLstater is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks for the reference ,can you please explain in simple terms that would be really helpful 2. how to relate lotus with E(X^2)=∑P(X)X^2   why is square not applied to X which is inside p(X)    ,   3.how to relate lotus with E(X−μ)2=∑P(X)(X−μ)2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120295/discussion-between-aj-mlstater-and-an-old-man-in-the-sea).